# Error 216 al crear un proyecto en Android Studio

Tags: java, android

He instalado `Android Studio` pero me sale el siguiente error al crear un proyecto:

> Error:CreateProcess error=216, Esta versión de %1 no es compatible con
>   la versión de Windows que está ejecutando. Compruebe la información de
>   sistema del equipo y después póngase en contacto con el anunciante de
>   software

según los requerimientos para `Android Studio` cumplo con el hardware necesario, tengo un sistema de 32 bits y ejecuto el .exe para 32 bits pero aun así me sigue saliendo el mismo error.

version de Android Studio 2.2

Muchas gracias por su atención y respuestas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Este detalle no es exclusivo de Android 2.2, la solucion en este caso es cambiar manualmente el path del JDK.

Entra al menu  `File` > `Project Structure` > `SDK Location`

En tu sistema debes reconocer el path y configurarlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En Windows:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Debemos tener en cuenta que podemos usar el embedded JDK que se tiene en la instalación de Android Studio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que generalmente se encuentra en la ruta:

**\Android Studio\jre**

u optar por no usar el instalado por Android Studio y usar el que instalamos desde el [sitio de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/install_overview.html):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

podemos encontrar el path como el definido en `JAVA_HOME` de las environment variables.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

En caso de no encontrarlo, podemos añadirlo de la siguiente manera:

- Dirigirse hacia propiedades del equipo (Click derecho en 'Equipo', presionar la opción 'Propiedades')
- Seleccionar 'Configuración avanzada del sistema' > 'Opciones avanzadas' > 'Variables de entorno' > En variables de usuario, 'Nueva...' y allí como nombre escribir **JAVA_HOME** y en su valor, la dirección de la ubicación de la carpeta del archivo jdk ya instalado, cuyo instalador puede descargarse desde [aquí](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQ4uS0nKnTAhWJEZAKHQ0KD-QQFggqMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2Ftechnetwork%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2Fdownloads%2Fjdk8-downloads-2133151.html&usg=AFQjCNEfygdKmZ1D2xJzvYIvnYbmmXWqsA&sig2=z37mxsFB-WjOCRvUlNenSw)

Comment: Tengo este mismo error, como se supone que soluciono, si no me deja agarrar la capeta del **jre** que se supone que todo mundo pone, solo me deja ponerle la carpeta del **jdk**

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales en realidad esa es la carpeta correcta si no usas el JRE instalado por Android Studio, Sería la del JDK, agregué más información. ᕦ ´• ᴥ •` ᕥ

Comment: Gracias maestro, eso hice agregue esa ruta